# Compute the $p$-adic order of $(p^n)! = p^n (p^n − 1) (p^n − 2) \cdots (2) 1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

This is a question from a book I'm struggling with, please could you provide a clear proof?

Compute the $p$-adic order of $(p^n)! = p^n (p^n − 1) (p^n − 2)  \cdots  (2)  1$.

kind thanks

Comment: What's the book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the $p$-adic order of $m!$ is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor\frac{m}{p^k}\right\rfloor$$

Set $m=p^n$.

Comment: so using this I would have $ord_{p}p^n=(p^{n-1})(p^{n-2})(p^{n-3})....(1)(p^{-1})(p^{-2})...$ so do I need to find what this infinite series converges to? (if it does) can you give me a concrete example? I will try some.

Comment: @MathproofP. No, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the "floor" function, so you wouldn't get into get negative powers. And $\sum$ is the sum symbol, not the product symbol.

Comment: is the answer $\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}$?

Comment: sorry that was for product

Comment: is it $\frac{1-p^n}{1-p}$?

Comment: Yes, that formula works

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

$$(1)\;\;\;\text{for}\;\;0\le k\le n\;,\;\;p^j\mid(p^n-k)\iff k=r\,p^j\;,\;\;\text{for some}\;\;0\le j\le n\;,\;\;r\in\Bbb N$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\text{Example:}\;\;\;(p^2)!=1\cdot\ldots\cdot p\cdot (p+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot 2p\cdot\ldots\cdot (p-1)p\cdot\ldots\cdot p^2=p^{3}\cdot K, \;\;\text{so}\ldots$$

Comment: So I'm trying to get
$(p^n)! = p^n (p^n − 1) (p^n − 2)  \cdots  (2)  1$. 
written as $p^k\frac{a}{b}$ so essential I guess I am trying to pull out as many factors of $p$ as possible whilst making sure $(a,p)=(b,p)=1$?
hint (1) seems to show that I can only pull out a factor of p if $k=rp^j$ so it works for r=0,1,... so for hint (2) I can't pull out a p for the first p-1 terms, I can pull out 1 p for p itself in the product and then one p from 2p=(p+p). Is this along the right lines? thanks v.much